# Facebook SDK not getting permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "dev-master".

Here is my code.

```
    $this->helper = new  Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost:8000/test2');

    $this->helper->getLoginUrl(['scope'=>'user_about_me,user_groups'])

   //test2 controller
    session_start();

    $session = $this->facebook->getSessionFromRedirect();       
    $request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/groups/');
    $response = $request->execute();

    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Here is the login link:

```
    https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=335104339978143&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Ftest2&amp;state=0d09d4965509ccb3dc78f2fffc44c11e&amp;sdk=php-sdk-4.1.0-wip&amp;scope=user_about_me%2C+user_groups
```

When I use the fb account that I registered the app, I can get the groups and the permission on login popups. But when I use other facebook accounts, the permission does not popup and I get no result.

Comment: I'm not getting pop-ups anymore asking for permission when i log to facebook.

Comment: 'other facebook accounts'..  is your app not 'live'? are they not test users?.. checking any exceptions?

Comment: its just on localhost. not test users and no exceptions. it works fine when i use the account of the i used to register the app but not  on other fb accounts

Comment: Correct, because the app is in development mode, and only developers and explicitly specified test users / testers can access the app.  Check the Roles section on developers.facebook.com and add users there.

Comment: Also, please don't require 'dev-master'..  breaking changes will break your app.  require '4.0.x' for now, and later upgrade to 4.1.x when it is released.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for additional permissions in the incorrect way. You need to do the following using Facebook PHP SDK v4.0.9:

```
// generate login url with scope, each permission as element in array
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) );

// output login link
echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Login</a>';
```

[Source](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/)

Comment: its just the same array () and []. the answer was I have to add the accounts as test users as what Fosco said. Thank you.

Comment: The difference was that you don't actually have to have the scope in there. Just the permissions as an array.

Comment: please help me with my other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065627/facebook-php-sdk-v4-redirect-when-already-logged