# Facebook PHP SDK v4 Redirect when already logged

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way to get the session when the user is already logged in?

I can only do

```
$session = $this->facebook->getSessionFromRedirect();
```

but I don't want the user to click the login link again.

Instead, when the user is already logged I just want to redirect and get the session to use

```
 $request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', 'url');
```

I've tried this

```
 $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['FBRLH_state']);
```

but I get an error

```
  Invalid OAuth access token.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is save the user's access_token to the session or cookie (e.g. under `fb_token`). Then, you can see if the cookie / session exists by checking if $_SESSION['fb_token'] is set.

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
}
```

The session will expire depending on your settings, so using $_COOKIE might be better.